# how to rename my file uploads and this file name following some data in DB

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have code to upload file like this ,this upload will save original name file,but i want to upload file with rename file original . my file name will following some data on database . where i can change my code for this problem ?

I have a table called 'format', from which table the file name file will be created. How do I enter data in the format format to change the original file name with an extension like the original file

```
public function proses_upload2(){

  $gambar = array();
  $jumlah = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

  for ($i=0; $i < $jumlah; $i++) { 
    $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];        
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "file/".$file_name);
    $gambar[$i] = $file_name;                 
  }     
                $nama_file1 = $gambar[0];
                $format_p2ptm ="Form Lap Haji"; 
                $tanggal =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//$this->input->post('waktu_upload'); 
                $jenis='p2si';


                $nama_file2 = $gambar[1];
                $format_p2ptm2 ="Form Lap KLB"; 
                $jenis='p2si';

                $nama_file3 = $gambar[2];
                $format_p2ptm3 ="Form Lap Imunisasi Balita, Bumil dan WUS";
                $jenis='p2si';

                $nama_file4 = $gambar[3];
                $format_p2ptm4 ="Form Lap Investigasi Final KIPI";
                $jenis='p2si';

                $nama_file5 = $gambar[4];
                $format_p2ptm5 ="Form Lap Stock + Harga Vaksin"; 
                $jenis='p2si';

                $nama_file6 = $gambar[5];
                $format_p2ptm6 ="Form Lap Campak";
                $jenis='p2si';



                if (!$nama_file1 == "") {
                $this->app_model->insert_data('penyakit', $format_p2ptm, $tanggal,$nama_file1,$jenis, $this->session->userdata('id_puskesmas'));
                }
                if (!$nama_file2 == "") {
                $this->app_model->insert_data('penyakit', $format_p2ptm2, $tanggal,$nama_file2,$jenis,$this->session->userdata('id_puskesmas'));
                }
                if (!$nama_file3 == "") {
                $this->app_model->insert_data('penyakit', $format_p2ptm3, $tanggal,$nama_file3,$jenis,$this->session->userdata('id_puskesmas'));
                }
                if (!$nama_file4 == "") {
                $this->app_model->insert_data('penyakit', $format_p2ptm4, $tanggal,$nama_file4,$jenis,$this->session->userdata('id_puskesmas'));
                }
                if (!$nama_file5 == "") {
                $this->app_model->insert_data('penyakit', $format_p2ptm5, $tanggal,$nama_file5,$jenis,$this->session->userdata('id_puskesmas'));
                }
                if (!$nama_file6 == "") {
                $this->app_model->insert_data('penyakit', $format_p2ptm6, $tanggal,$nama_file6,$jenis,$this->session->userdata('id_puskesmas'));
                }





            redirect('puskesmas/view_puskesmas1');

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, do you want to create a random file name to the uploaded file then save that new name in db?

Comment: A bit confused: you seem to not be using codeigniter's built-in upload library, although you tagged the question as codeigniter. Are you able to refactor your code and use CI's upload library? If so, renaming the uploaded file is a one liner

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];` use the name of you choice.

Comment: but I want to name the file automatically. if the user enters the name hello.xlsx, the system will automatically change the name hello.xlsx to the name that is adjusted to the specified format

Comment: All I meant was to build the logic to create the dynamic filename separately and just give that name while calling `move_uploaded_files`. It would be helpful if you could explain how 'dynamic' your filenames would be. Is there any logic for that?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have a table called 'format'. table format contains some data, such as A, B, C, D. only the data is in the 'format' table. then in the script in my post above is the file upload process, where the file is in the form / extension xlsx / xls (ms.excel file). the user who has a file called Hello.xlsx when uploaded the file name will change to A.xlsx. and To Upload the 2nd column will change to B.xlsx and so on

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbEeZ.png)

Comment: Instead of $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]; add this code
$_FILES['userfile']['name']= 'File-name'; In for loop